# split data according to N number of categories with X number of total data limit

Tags: php

OK. I am working in a `PHP` project.

and I have some categorized data in my database -

For example- I have data of Three Categories.

> Category 1 
>   Category 2 
>   Category 3

Categories could be changed. Like 2,3,4,5 etc.

And i have facility to show a limit of data.

Ex. Lets say Admin want to show only 9 Records

So now we have three categories and x limit (which is 9 according to example). and best thing is that-

**I need to show N numbers of records from each category and total X records.**

Here N numbers is for each Category. So it will look like this:

> N1 + N2 + N3 = X (limit ex. 9)
>
> N1 from Category1
>  N2 from Category2
>  N3 from Category3

So basically i have formulated it like this -

> NumberOfRecordPerCategory = X (limit) / N (Number of Categories)

But it is actually working if i set the limit multiple of 3 like 6,9,12 etc.

So my Question is-

> How do i manage the total records according to limit (X) - 
>   1. if Admin set the limit which is not multiple by 3 like 8,10,11, etc.
>   2. if Admin change the number of category Like 2 or 4, then how could i manage this?

Please give some idea about this. and please let me know if Question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would choose for your requirement is ceil (round fractions up). If there is some fractions because the number is not multiple by 3, for example 11 with 3 categories, then have the limitation of 4,4,3 for each category. This could be done by having two limit values: limit of total, limit per category.
Here's my suggestion for your needs (code) :

```
<?php

/*

$data = array (
"category1" => array (1,2,3,4,5),
"category2" => array (10,20,30,40,50),
"category3" => array (100,200,300,400,500),
);
*/

$limit = 11; // given by the admin
$number_of_categories = count($data);
$limit_per_category = ceil ( $limit / $number_of_categories ); // ceil (11 / 3) = 4

$cnt = 0; // tracking the total number of retrieved data.
foreach ($data as $row) {
  $cnt_category = 0;
  foreach ($row as $item) {
    echo $item . "\n"; // print the first N (NumberOfRecordPerCategory) data
    $cnt_category++;

    $cnt++;
    if ($cnt >= $limit) break; // exit the loop
    if ($cnt_category >= $limit_per_category) break; // move to next category
  } 
  if ($cnt >= $limit) break; // exit the loop     
}
```